# Powershell split sections by regex

Tags: powershell

In order to create a script which allows me to perform a firewall migration, i have the need to understand how to split an output into sections with Powershell.

The firewall (which is a Sonicwall, if it helps) produces an output, which is delimited by sections. For example:

```
--System Information--
[Data]
--Network Interfaces--
[Data]
--User Objects Table--
[Data]
...
```

You can see that the output is delimited by these sections, for which i have produced a regex:

```
$regex1='^--(\w*|\w+ \w+|\w+ \w+ \w+|\w+ \w+ \w+ \w+)--$'
```

I don't understand however, how can i produce an output which helps me put a specific section title above, and the data directly below. I don't want all of them, just specific outputs from specific sections.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: give an example what is the expected output

Comment: Hello f6a4. The expected output would be something like:


--System Information--
[Data]
...



But only for the fields I'm calling. For example if the first field is "System Information", then the data should be stored (I believe) in an array and then called upon $item[0] for further manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

A complex multi-line regex might be a bit to much in your case. A very simple approach would be to go through the content line by line:

```bsh
$content = @"
--System Information--
[Data1]
--Network Interfaces--
[Data2]
[Data3]
--User Objects Table--
[Data4]
"@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$dataDict = @{}
foreach ($line in $content)
{   
    # Each section opens a new entry in the $dataDict hash table.
    # Anything else that follows, gets added to this entry.
    if($line -match '^--(.+)--$')
    {
        $section = $Matches[1]
        $dataDict[$section] = @()
    }
    else 
    {
        $dataDict[$section] += $line
    }
}
# You can now narrow down the resulting object to the properties, 
# that you are interested in.
[pscustomobject]$dataDict | 
    Select-Object 'System Information', 'Network Interfaces' | 
    Format-List
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel for your input. I've tried your script (making very few adaptations). Would this work also for files in input? 
For example `$file = Get.Content C:\test.txt`

Comment: Of course!  That is why I am splitting the test string in the beginning of the file. It mimics the output that `Get-Content C:\test.txt` would give you.

Comment: Thanks Manuel, your script works for the basic input, but I'm still unable to get it working with a file or for the complete text: While I'm working with the complete text pasted in, the script returns the whole output of the file and not the single sections (e.g. only the _--Network Interfaces--_ section). Do you have an idea on what it might be? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer an approach with a data table:

```
$configFile = 'C:\sonciwall\sonicwall.txt'

$dt = New-Object system.Data.DataTable
[void]$dt.Columns.Add('Section',[string]::empty.GetType() )
[void]$dt.Columns.Add('Data',[string]::empty.GetType() )

foreach( $line in Get-Content $configFile ) {

    $line = $line.Trim()

    if( !$line ) {
        Continue       # skip empty lines
    }
    elseif( $line -like '--*' ) {
        $section = $line
        Continue
    }
    else {
        $data    = $line
    }

    $newRow = $dt.NewRow()
    $newRow.Section = $section
    $newRow.Data    = $data
    [void]$dt.Rows.Add( $newRow )

}

# Get specific information from a specific section using sql syntax:

$dt.Select("Section = '--System Information--' AND Data = 'foo'")

# Update specific information in all secions:

$rows = $dt.Select("Data = 'foo'")

foreach( $row in $rows ) {
    $row.Data = 'foo bar'
    [void]$dt.AcceptChanges()
}
```

Comment: Thanks f6a4, the approach seems to be fine. For testing i tried to print the first '--System Information--' section after selecting the relevant area, and it only returns to me `System.Data.DataRow` recursively. Do you have any idea why is this? Thanks

Comment: Try $dt.Select("Section = '--System Information--'") | % { $_.Section; $_.Data }

Comment: Hi f6a4, I tried putting that in a Write-Host clause but doesn't return any results.